# AsyncTask onPostExecute received wrong parameter

Tags: android

I have a simple AsyncTask class on Android, and I noticed that I always get the positive result passed to onPostExecute method even though I know that doInBackground returns negative.

Please take a look at my code. I run this code on debug and I confirm that I land on the exception block and I return false. but it is not reflected on onPostExecute.

```
public class AsyncSendOSCTask extends AsyncTask<OSCMessage, Void, Boolean> {

private OSCPortOut oscPortOut;
private Activity activity;

public AsyncSendOSCTask(Activity activity, OSCPortOut oscPortOut) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.oscPortOut = oscPortOut;
}   

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(OSCMessage... message) {
    try {

        this.oscPortOut.send(message[0]);
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
    catch(Exception exp) {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {
    if(!result.booleanValue()) { // this is always true!!!          
        Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Error Sending OSC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

What am I missing here? Thanks for your help...

Comment: you are returning true always. Why do u think it will go in catch and return false?

Comment: @AND_DEV Nope, he said he entered catch block when debugging.

Comment: That's pretty very strange. Are you sure the result you got is true from a log, or did you assume it because Toast did not show?

Comment: oh.. well OSC messages are sent over the network. send() method throws exception when the host ip is wrong, for example. and I enter the catch block on debug...

Comment: try to print result.booleanValue() in log. Is it really true out there?

Comment: would be interesting if you could comment-out all the code in `doInBackground()` and replace it with `return Boolean.FALSE;` (only)

Comment: @DavidM I changed true to false, and I received false on result.booleanValue() and I saw the Toast message on the screen

Comment: i *think* that tells me that you're not getting an exception then, right?

Comment: I am positive that I land on the exception block as I step through the code line by line in debug mode. (I am sorry if I misunderstood you)

Comment: how about replacing the code with a simple `return Boolean.FALSE;`. make that the only executable code in `doInBackground()`. i bet that works. It would certainly prove that `AsyncTask` is working as expected. (i don't see anything wrong with your code)

Comment: simply return FALSE gives false on onPostExecute. I just realized that this could be a problem related to eclipse. eclipse debugger stops at both "return true" (in try) and "return false" (in exception). That must have confused me, leading me to think that I was actually getting an exception. I will just stop worrying about this. Thanks a lot for your input, and sorry for taking your time...

Answer (score 0):

In case of that your problem is still there:

pls try this:

> public class AsyncSendOSCTask extends AsyncTask {
>
> private OSCPortOut oscPortOut; private Activity activity;boolean examplebool; //added examplebool
>
> public AsyncSendOSCTask(Activity activity, OSCPortOut oscPortOut) {
>       this.activity = activity;
>       this.oscPortOut = oscPortOut; }
>
> @Override protected Boolean doInBackground(OSCMessage... message) {
>       try {
>
> ```
>     this.oscPortOut.send(message[0]);
>     examplebool=true; // added
>     return(examplebool); //edited
> }
> catch(Exception exp) {
>     examplebool=false; //added
>     return(examplebool); //edited
> } }
> ```
>
> @Override protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {
>       if(!result.booleanValue()) { // this is always true!!!
>           Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Error Sending OSC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>       } }

it's fast handcoded and not tested you may change your onPostExecute too.